# SwiftUI and RealityKit: Updating ARView based on TimerController

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, augmented-reality, realitykit

I am working on a SwiftUI app that includes an ARView using RealityKit. I have a TimerController class that manages a countdown timer, and I want to display the current timer value in the ARView.

Here's my TimerController class:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TimerController: ObservableObject {
    var tempoTotalTimer = 40
    @Published var tempo: Int = 0
    @Published var navigationLinkAtivo = false
    @Published var timerIsOver = false
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var timerIsOverCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    @EnvironmentObject var audioPlayer:AudioPlayer
    @EnvironmentObject var gameController:GameController

    init() {
        startTimer()
    }

    deinit {
        stopTimer()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if self.tempo > 0 {
                //self.tempo -= 1
            } else {
                self.stopTimer()
            }
            print(self.tempo)
        }
        
        tempo = tempoTotalTimer
        timerIsOver = false

        // Utilize Combine para refletir as mudanças no contador
        cancellable = $tempo
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                guard self != nil else { return }
                // Faça algo quando o contador mudar, se necessário
            }
        
        timerIsOverCancellable = $timerIsOver
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                guard self != nil else { return }
                // Faça algo quando o contador mudar, se necessário
            }
    }

    func stopTimer() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        cancellable?.cancel()
        cancellable = nil
        timerIsOver = true
        timerIsOverCancellable?.cancel()
        timerIsOverCancellable = nil
    }
}
```

And here's the SwiftUI ARViewContainer:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import UIKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var gameplayViewModel = GameplayViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var timerController:TimerController
    
    var body: some View {
       
        ARViewContainer(timer: $timerController.tempo, operacaoMatematica: $gameplayViewModel.operacaoMatematica)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var timer: Int
    @Binding var operacaoMatematica: String
    
    let numbersPosition = [[-0.09, 0.1, -0.25], [-0.01, 0.1, -0.25], [0.07, 0.1, -0.25],
                           [-0.09, 0, -0.25], [-0.01, 0, -0.25], [0.07, 0, -0.25]]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Bola
        let ballEntity = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "ball.usdc")
        ballEntity.scale = [0.02, 0.02, 0.02]
        let anchorBall = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
        anchorBall.addChild(ballEntity)
        anchorBall.position = [0, 0, 0.2]
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorBall)
        
        // Trave
        let goalEntity = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "gol.usdc")
        goalEntity.scale = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
        let anchorGoal = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
        anchorGoal.addChild(goalEntity)
        anchorGoal.position = [0, 0, -0.2]
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorGoal)
        
        // Botões e palpites
        var buttonsArrayEntity: [Entity] = []
        
        for index in 0...5 {
            let buttonsEntity = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "botaoGol\(index + 1)")
            buttonsArrayEntity.append(buttonsEntity)
            let anchorButtons = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
            buttonsArrayEntity[index].scale = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]
            buttonsArrayEntity[index].generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            anchorButtons.addChild(buttonsArrayEntity[index])
            anchorButtons.position = [0, 0, -0.2]
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorButtons)
            
            let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText(" ", extrusionDepth: 0.1, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 2))
            let textMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .black, isMetallic: true)
            let textEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh, materials: [textMaterial])
            let anchorPalpiteText = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
            textEntity.scale = SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.03, y: 0.03, z: 0.1)
            textEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            anchorPalpiteText.addChild(textEntity)
            anchorPalpiteText.position = SIMD3<Float>(x: Float(numbersPosition[index][0]), y: Float(numbersPosition[index][1]), z: Float(numbersPosition[index][2]))
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorPalpiteText)
        }
        
        //Cronometro
        makeTimer(arView: arView, timer: context.coordinator.timer)
        
        //fundo placar
        let fundoContaMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.08, depth: 0.01)
        let fundoContaMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: false)
        let fundoContaEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: fundoContaMesh, materials: [fundoContaMaterial])
        let anchorFundoConta = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
        anchorFundoConta.addChild(fundoContaEntity)
        anchorFundoConta.position = [-0.01,0.28,-0.26]
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorFundoConta)
        
        //conta
        let textContaMesh = MeshResource.generateText("\(operacaoMatematica)", extrusionDepth: 0.1, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 2))
        let textContaMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)
        let textContaEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: textContaMesh, materials: [textContaMaterial])
        let anchorContaText = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
        textContaEntity.scale = SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.03, y: 0.03, z: 0.1)
        anchorContaText.addChild(textContaEntity)
        anchorContaText.position = [-0.1,0.25,-0.25]
        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorContaText)
        
        // Adicionar a entidade à cena
        return arView
    }
    
    //from SWiftUI to UIKit
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
        makeTimer(arView: uiView, timer: context.coordinator.timer)
    }
    
    func makeTimer(arView: ARView, timer: Int)  {
        let arViewTimer = arView
        let textTimerMesh = MeshResource.generateText("\(timer)", extrusionDepth: 0.1, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 2))
        let textTimerMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .white, isMetallic: false)
        let textTimerEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: textTimerMesh, materials: [textTimerMaterial])
        let anchorTimerText = AnchorEntity(.plane(.horizontal, classification: [.floor, .table], minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2]))
        textTimerEntity.scale = SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.03, y: 0.03, z: 0.1)
        anchorTimerText.addChild(textTimerEntity)
        anchorTimerText.position = [0.2,0.4,-0.25]
        arViewTimer.scene.addAnchor(anchorTimerText)
    }
        
    //from UIKit to SwifUi
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(timer: $timer, operacaoMatematica: $operacaoMatematica)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject{
        @Binding var timer: Int
        @Binding var operacaoMatematica: String
        
        init(timer: Binding<Int>, operacaoMatematica: Binding<String>){
            self._timer = timer
            self._operacaoMatematica = operacaoMatematica
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update the ARView with the current value of timer from the TimerController. However, I'm unsure about the correct way to access and update this data in the ARViewContainer.

How can I properly bind the timer variable from TimerController to the ARViewContainer and ensure that the ARView updates dynamically as the timer changes? Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should go through the Interfacing with UIKit tutorial. There is quite a bit “wrong” with your code but the worst one is calling make inside update without any protections, second is putting Binding in a class.